# How do I change a feature branch of a local git repo without changing the master branch?

Tags: python, git

I have a project like this, that I've cloned from github.

```
top
   --init.py
```

I've created a branch feature_1,
but whenever I checkout the branch, and add a file to the top level directory (ie test.py), the master branch is changed...

can anyone suggest reasons why? If it helps, I'm using pycharm...

Comment: When you are on your feature branch and then you create a file it "changes" the master branch? Does this happen when you commit on your feature branch? What does "changing the master branch" constitute? Does a commit get added on top of master?

Comment: the master branch is identical to the feature branch...i hesitate to commit to the feature  branch as I am inexperienced with git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not committing, you're not changing *any* branch, you're just changing the files in your working tree. Make your changes and *commit* them to the feature branch. That will make those changes part of the feature branch, and they won't appear on master. As long as you don't commit, git won't touch your changes at all, even if you switch branches. The rule with git is commit early and often.

Comment: @coderboi the directory you checked your project out to.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a

```
git stash
```

or alternatively a

```
git add <filename>
git commit -m "<my commit message>"
```

These options would ensure that your feature branch has the local file either in a dirty working directory ([git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)) or in a [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) before swapping over to your master branch.